# How to install tsim-0.84 on Windows 10 with Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, x11

For a laboration in class we are using an old train simulator for Linux called tsim. I am trying to get this to run on my Windows 10 laptop with Cygwin but I get an error when running the "make" command.

```
AddToggleWidget.c:3:27: fatal error: X11/Intrinsic.h: No such file or directory
```

The thing is I think the simulator is so old that it wants to use this `X11/Intrinsic.h` from an old library called xorg-x11-devel. Because I already have it in a newer one called libXt-devel. This is based on this old [cygwin thread](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-xfree/2008-11/msg00364.html).

I have looked everywhere for a way to get the xorg-x11-devel library but can't find it so any help would be greatly appreciated.

[The laboration.](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/course/TDA383/lab1.html)

[The Train Simulator, tsim(source code).](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2013/course/TDA382_Concurrent_Programming_HT2013/assignments/1/downloads/tsim-0.84.tar.gz)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the libXt-devel package. 
To verify if the libXt-devel is properly installed

```
$ cygcheck -c libXt-devel
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
libXt-devel          1.1.5-1        OK
```

As it seems that instead your real problem is how to build tsim on cygwin and you are focusing on the wrong issue, I will also provide you the recipe I used.
The following patch is needed for proper build and link:

```
--- orig/tsim-0.84/src/Makefile.am      2008-09-10 12:45:17.000000000 +0200
+++ tsim-0.84/src/Makefile.am   2016-09-05 22:06:47.665318000 +0200
@@ -11,5 +11,6 @@
 tsim_CFLAGS = -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes \
               -DRESDIR=\"${datadir}/tsim\"

-tsim_LDFLAGS = -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lXaw -lXt -lXmu -lX11 -lXext
+tsim_LDFLAGS = -L/usr/lib
+tsim_LDADD = -largp

--- orig/tsim-0.84/src/bitmap.c 2008-09-08 13:14:16.000000000 +0200
+++ tsim-0.84/src/bitmap.c      2016-09-05 22:14:02.032117400 +0200
@@ -17,14 +17,14 @@
 static void GetBitmapPath(
       String name,
       String full_name) {
-  sprintf(full_name, "%s/%s/%s", app_dir(), bitmap_dir(), name);
+  sprintf(full_name, "%s%s/%s", app_dir(), bitmap_dir(), name);
 }

 void ReadCustomBitmaps(
       Widget w) {
   char custom_directory[BUFSIZE];

-  sprintf(custom_directory, "%s/%s/customBitmaps", app_dir(), bitmap_dir());
+  sprintf(custom_directory, "%s%s/customBitmaps", app_dir(), bitmap_dir());
   gBitmapDirectory = BDAddDirectory(w, custom_directory, NULL);
 }

--- orig/tsim-0.84/src/pipe.c   2008-09-09 12:55:58.000000000 +0200
+++ tsim-0.84/src/pipe.c        2016-09-05 18:47:40.261754300 +0200
@@ -3,6 +3,7 @@
 #include <stdlib.h>      /* exit */
 #include <unistd.h>      /* read */
 #include <sys/param.h>    /* MIN, MAX */
+#include <sys/socket.h>

 #if defined sun3 || defined sun4
   #include <sys/filio.h>
```

Makefile.am is changed as `/usr/X11R6/lib` has been replace long time ago by `/usr/lib` and the libs should be put in LDADD not on LDFLAGS to avoid  problem of order durink linking . `-largp` is missing from the requirement while the the other libs will be correctly added during `configure`
The changes in bitmap.c are needed to avoid wrongly loading default data. Cygwin have a dedicate meaning for path starting with "//" that are a side effect of current code.

Step by step instruction:
- install `libargp-devel`, `libX11-devel`, `libXaw-devel`, `libXext-devel`, `libXmu-devel`,  `libXt-devel`
- unpack the tsim-0.84.tar.gz
- apply the patch
- run `autoreconf` , it will properly rebuilds the `Makefile.in`
- run `./configure`  it will properly rebuilds the `Makefile`
- run `make`
- run `make install`
- run `tsim`

As bonus, how the program looks:

[image]

Comment: I realize that my title may be a bit misleading, but you clearly didn't read the post. As I stated I already have this package:
`$ cygcheck -p X11/Intrinsic.h
Found 2 matches for X11/Intrinsic.h
libXt-devel-1.1.4-2 - libXt-devel: X.Org X Toolkit library (installed binaries and support files)
libXt-devel-1.1.5-1 - libXt-devel: X.Org X Toolkit library (installed binaries and support files)`

Comment: I read your post, and I answered how to install `X11/Intrinsic.h`. If you want to know how to build tsim that is a different question. FYI  `cygcheck -p` ask the cywin server not your local installation. `cygcheck -c` check your installation.

Comment: Like I said, I already have this library installed but the tsim "make" doesn't recognize it. That's why I want to install an older package containing `X11/Intrinsic.h`.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, only a windows user, first time cygwin so had no idea that tsim needed to be fixed like that!

Comment: guess I spoke too soon. I have done everything you said in your post and I is still missing the X11 library...

Comment: what is the output of `cygcheck -c libXt-devel` ? Are you sure to have recent cygwin installation ?

Comment: Output: `$ cygcheck -c libXt-devel
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
libXt-devel          1.1.5-1        OK`
And i just updated to the latest version.

This is a bit concerning tho: `$ cygcheck -c libargp-devel
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
` Seems to not exist.

When running `./configure` it can't find any of the X librarys

Comment: I will say that I am unsure that I have applied the patch changes correctly. I simply edited the files in notepad according to what you wrote. Unsure about spaces and indentations though.

Comment: The patch does not change the X11 header search.  I suggest you to follow https://cygwin.com/problems.html and ask on the cygwin mailing list https://cygwin.com/lists.html

Comment: Since this is only one lab that needs to be done in 2-3 weeks I think I will just use the school's Linux computers for this one. Thanks for your time and effort though!